# Javascript function two open windows are not working

Tags: javascript

i know this is a redundant question, but those articles in google did not help me literally because my approach was different i guess, but here it is, two open windows are not working even tho i loop it. i only receive the first item of array which is facebook.com

```
var link = function (){
    var websites = ['www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com']
   for(var x = 0; x < websites.length; x++){
       window.open(websites[x])
   }
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
var link = function (){
       
          window.open('www.facebook.com')
             window.open('www.google.com')
    }
```

same result, gives me fb.com

Comment: use window.location.href

Comment: Is the second one getting blocked? Open up the dev tools and see.

Comment: Most browsers disallow opening multiple windows at the same time by default. As a programmer, there's no way to override this. If the user explicitly whitelists your site in the settings of their browser, then your code will work.

Comment: Hi @rags2riches, does not working as well. it is just replacing my current web page, i want new window

Comment: see my answer below where I address this issue

Comment: yes @PaulRooney not executing after the first one executed

Comment: @rags2riches only facebook was opening just like before

Comment: did you see my test on jsbin? Can you update your code to show me what changes you implemented ?

Comment: thank you for that information @FZs

Comment: i have nothing changes @rags2riches, anw thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `https` protocol in your url strings, inside the array.
Second, for each element in your loop, use `window.open()` passing a second argument `"_blank"` to open the urls in new tabs, respectively.

```
function link () {
    var websites = ['https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.google.com']
    for (var x = 0; x < websites.length; x++) {
        var website = websites[x];
        window.open(website, "_blank");
    }
}

link();
```

Tested in:

https://jsbin.com/fezolavepa/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

Normally the code you wrote should work, but the reason why it isn't is because the browser detected Pop-ups.

You can query the user to disable pop ups for your site in order to get full functionality

Or you can use this instead

```
var link = function (){
var websites = ['www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com']
for(var x = 0; x < websites.length; x++){
   setTimeout(() => {window.open(websites[x], '_blank)}, 2000)
}
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: If that still doesn't work, then I'm afraid your only option is to tell the user to disable Pop ups